# How to slide two elements apart as page scrolls down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-events

Can someone help suggest a good way to achieve the following please?

I want two overlapping images (doesn't really matter that they're images) to **slide apart as the page scrolls down and they come into view**, and **slide back together as they go out of view**. Think of how a zip works.

From another script I think it could be achieved by adapting the following but I still can't get my head around it:

```
var top = $('.container').offset().top - parseFloat($('.container').css('margin-top').replace(/auto/, 0));
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
var y = $(this).scrollTop();
if (y >= top) {
  $('.imageA').addClass('moveLeft');
  $('.imageB').addClass('moveRight');
  }
else {
  $('.imageA').removeClass('moveLeft');
  $('.imageB').removeClass('moveRight');
  }
});
```

But this would only trigger the event once as the `.container` comes into view.

How can I make it so that the more the container scrolls into view, the more the distance between the images increases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just setting/removing a class, so you aren't going to get animated movement. You should try setting position or margins relative to the `y` variable.

simple example to give you an idea:

```
.left {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #f99;
    position: absolute;
    right: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
}

.right {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #9f9;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
}

$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    $('.left').css('marginRight', y/5);
    $('.right').css('marginLeft', y/5);
});
```

See jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/shooter/LcEZy/1/)

Comment: Yeah I figured as much, but I thought I would give a starting point for someone to be able to help. Adding/removing a class or setting a position in itself won't solve the issue. Like you say, the gap between the elements will need to be relative to something.

Comment: That's about right. Then once the container begins to scroll out of the viewport, the items move back together. But that's certainly the basic idea, thanks.

Comment: Ok, hope it helps as a starting point. The JavaScript should be pretty easy, it's always the CSS that I struggle with when trying to do things like this.

Comment: Make that a SO snippet too.